# Difference between quadric and conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, surfaces, quadrics

What is the difference between a conic and a quadric? I'm guessing that this depends on your ambient space? I think that conics are just special quadrics and are a codimension 1 object and a quadric is the space that gets cut out by a quadric polynomial in any ambient space? Is that correct? For example, would

$$\left\{[u:v:w]\in \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2 \; \vert \; u^2 +3v^2 -vw = 0\right\}$$

be a conic (and quadric) hypersurface, but

$$\left\{[u:v:w:z]\in \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^3 \; \vert \; u^2 +3v^2 -vw = 0\right\}$$

is a quadric hypersurface? Or is it too much to talk about projective space? Or maybe I have to be in Real space? Thanks for the help.

Comment: As for the usage I saw, a "conic" is the zero of a $\deg=2$ polynomial in a bi-dimensional space (whether it is $\mathbb{RP}^2,\mathbb{CP}^2,\mathbb{RA}^2,\mathbb{CA}^2$ it depends on the context), while a "quadric" is the zero of a $\deg=2$ polynomial in a general affine/projective space. I might be inaccurate, though.

Comment: OK thanks. That's what I tried to say in my question but you said in much more clearly and compactly. Well since nobody else said anything, that's what I'm going to go with. Makes sense to me. Thanks! And if you feel confident to make that an answer I will select it.

Comment: A conic is a one-dimensional quadric. End of story.